# regex to match everything

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to match everything:

```
/^(?=.{10,8000}$).*$/
```

But now I just realize that `.*` doesn't match the newline character. How can I make this regular expression match newlines?

Comment: Add the multiline and global flag to the regex construct. var regex = new RegExp("^(?=.{10,8000}$).*$", "gim")

Comment: Using a `{,}` repetition rule *and* match line breaks can be tricky. How many characters are there in a line break on your platform? On mine?

Comment: I will leave a compensantion in the 10,8000 repetition rule, like 10,7950. This way it will not throw a exception in the database. thx

Comment: @myself Why do you want to use a regex for this? It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All whitespace + non-whitespace = all characters: `[\S\s]`

```
/^(?=[\S\s]{10,8000})[\S\s]*$/
```

Comment: @myself Actually it does. Although in general I have no idea why you need a regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filter =  /.*/gim;
```

That will match everything across multiple lines.

Comment: `/.*/gim.exec("a\nb")` only matches `a` when I insert it into devtools or nodejs-repl.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is pretty much simpler, just use
`/.*/`
. stands for any character and * allows any repetition of that character.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a regex?

```
var txt = "Hello World!";
if(length(txt) >= 10 && length(txt) <= 8000) {//match}
```

Comment: Bro, hehe, we already meet on here, and thats because Ill not be rude. My project have a validation layer shared between js and c#. All fields have a acronym that determines what pattern will be use to validate it. The layer is working very well, keeping the validation consistent in the client side, the server side, and the database. This layer validation uses only regex to validade, its why Im not doing that (and Im not planning to extend or refactor this layer because my problem is trivial and still fits the layer).

Answer (score 0):

1.use this

```
 var filter = /[\w|\W]*/gim;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.